# how to reinitalize vhost configuration in wamp?

Tags: apache, wamp, vhosts

i have moved the folder of my application in wamp/www and change the path accordingly in my vhost file ( httpd-vhosts.conf).

i then restart all services in wamp and the changes are not effective.
Is there a cache to clear or something?

Comment: What do you see when you navigate to the vhosts? 404s?

Comment: if i type down in firefox the url i have defined ?empty content

Comment: You get a blank page? Have you checked your server logs?